# Background-image Fade when Portfolio Icon is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm currently stumped and hope I can get some help.  I'm working on a project where the client wants a background-image to fade when an icon is clicked.

You can see the piece I'm referring to at: http://209.142.68.153/#work-showcase

For example, if someone clicks the second icon, the main background above it would fade in to that piece of work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While cross fades typically look the best, that generally involves complications like using a container div with its position set to relative, then two child divs set to: (position:absolute;top:0;left:0;).

Instead, you can fade using the opacity, then, on complete, change the image and fade back in.

```
$('.gallery a').click(function() {
  var linkElement = $(this);
  $('.work-header').animate({opacity:0}, 1000, function() {
    // <li id="filename1"> ... </li>
    var filename = linkElement.closest('li').attr('id');
    $('.work-header').css('background-image', 'url(path/to/' + filename + '.jpg)');

    // You will highly likely want to implement an "onLoad" for
    // the image above because it will start fading back in
    // whether or not the image has finished loading.
    $('.work-header').animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Caleb, this worked perfectly.  My only issue now is -- There are 21 icons.  Each will have a different image associated with it to load at the top.  How can I easily manage that?  Can I set it look for an ID on the <li> tag if the background filenames were consistent?

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you had success with it! As for loading the images... there are a ton of ways to go about doing that... personally I would write an AddThumb() function that you pass the parameters to. Otherwise, as you said, just grabbing the ID from the parent works. I'll update my code to reflect how to do this for you.

Comment: Caleb,  I'm pretty sure I've added everything like you said for the added images -- it doesn't seem to be working now though.

I did fix the .attr('id); -- I made it .attr('id');

Comment: Caleb, more information -- if I right-click on the area the background should appear -- it is saying the image is named "undefined.jpg"

Comment: Ah, the 'this' was in the wrong scope. I've added a variable to the appropriate scope for tracking the clicked link, rather than targeting '.work-header'. That should work. :)

Comment: Caleb, can you talk about the "onLoad" issue you commented about in the code?  Do I need to do this?